# Uncaught (in promise) for Mock-promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I went through other similar posts and they all mention that I need to specify catch block with my promise instead of second param in then(`onSuccess`, `onRejected`).

However I realize if I change `myPromise.then(onSuccess, onRejected)` to `myPromise.then(onSuccess).catch(onRejected)` then catch block is never executed and error still shows up in chrome dev console.

```js
// Verifiers
const verifyOnFulfilled = (result) => {
  expect(result).toEqual(expectedOnFulfilledResponse);
};

const verifyOnRejected = (result) => {
  expect(result).toEqual(expectedOnRejectedResponse);
};

// Mocking a server call and this catch statement does nothing.
// Added just to test if this fixes the prob
mockPromise.catch((e) => {
  return e;
});

// Mock request bind. Ignore this
requestSpy.and.returnValue(mockPromise);

// Call the api
const promiseA = myService.deleteItem(id); // It will create a new mock promise
promiseA.then(verifyOnFulfilled, verifyOnRejected);
// promiseA.then(verifyOnFulfilled).catch(verifyOnRejected); // If I use this then catch function is never executed.

// Run mock promises
MockPromises.executeForPromise(promiseA);
```

API call block:

```js
let deleteRequestPromise = ... // some internal generic way to create promise

  return deleteRequestPromise.then(
    () => {
      return commentId;
    },
    (error) => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
```

Comment: is `myService.deleteItem(id)` erroring out? i.e statusCode !== 2xx?

Comment: your do `return e;`  which passes the error. If you just do a `console.log('Error but i don't care')` instead you will not see the error

Comment: No, deleteItem(id) doesn't error. @Stamos I tried but still got error

Comment: Can you please include the error?